# How to install non-outdated nvidia drivers using apt-get?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, apt, drivers, nvidia

I tried using `apt-get install nvidia-current` after installation
I got `280.13` version, which is not the latest version(`290.10`).
so how can i force `apt-get` to download the latest driver?

Edit:

I'm on Linux Mint 12 and it was just released, so I think it is possible to get
the latest driver.

Comment: in general when you are using the `apt-get` and you didn't change the default repos, you are going to get the nvidia drivers that are in the repos, and those whom in charge of the repos decides what is going to be there. so you are left with two options, add a repo that have the `290.10` drivers and it is compatible with your distro, or install the drivers from a standalone package that you download form someware.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you are using the `apt-get` and you didn't change the default repos, you are going to get the nvidia drivers that are in the repos, and those who are in charge of the repos decide what is going to be there.

So you are left with two options:

- add a repo that has the 290.10 drivers and is compatible with your distro, or
- install the drivers from a standalone package that you download from [nvidia's site](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)